# How do I pass a standalone template function to a standard algorithm as a BinaryOperation argument?

Tags: c++, templates

I have an `std::vector<int> v1` of size `n`, and I want to build an `std::vector<int> v2` such as for every `i` from `[0, n)` `v2[i] = max(v1[i], ..., v1[n-1])`.

I wanna use a standard algorithm `std::parial_sum` for it, something like

```
std::partial_sum(v1.rbegin(), v1.rend(), v2.rbegin(), std::max);
```

The only problem is that it doesn't compile, as I get an `couldn't deduce template parameter '_BinaryOperation'` error for `std::max`.

[Documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sum) for `std::partial_sum` suggests a concise syntax like

```
std::partial_sum(first, last, d_first, std::plus<>());
```

but `std::plus` is a class with an overloaded `operator()`, not a standalone function. What can I do to use `std::max` in a similar way?

Comment: Why not just use a lambda?

Comment: @heapunderrun because it would be *less concise*? =)
Sure, I admit that it's possible. Just as it would be possible without using `std::partial_sum` at all. Consider this an act of cusiosity, *how do I use regular functions instead of callable objects*

Comment: Note that `std::max` is **not** among the designated [addressable functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Addressing_restriction). So you should not pass its address anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a regular function as a callable object, because functions are not objects.

Either use a lambda:

```
std::partial_sum(v1.rbegin(), v1.rend(), v2.rbegin(), [](auto lhs, auto rhs) {
    return std::max(lhs, rhs);
});
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WdzxM5s7z)
Note that you can have that lambda as a separate variable too:

```
auto max = [](auto lhs, auto rhs) { return std::max(lhs, rhs); };
std::partial_sum(v1.rbegin(), v1.rend(), v2.rbegin(), max);
```

Or make your own callable object:

```
struct max {
    template<typename T>
    auto operator()(T const& lhs, T const& rhs) {
        return std::max(lhs, rhs);
    }
};
// [...]
std::partial_sum(v1.rbegin(), v1.rend(), v2.rbegin(), max{});
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YPPqbxfGx)

Comment: Okay, fair enough, I missed the part in the doc for `std::partial_sum` where `op` is explicitly defined as "binary operation function *object*". So yeah, you're right, no way around it but to make such an object.

Comment: @Semisonic That's one of the main reasons lambdas were introduced. In C++ and many other similar languages, functions are not first-class citizens, and as such cannot be passed around as a function argument. You can of course pass function pointers, but this can be tricky and limits the type of argument (unless you write additional overloads).

Answer (score 0):

You could define your own Max Struct comparator:

```
template<class T>
struct Mymax{
   T& operator()(const T& a, const T& b)
   {
      return (a < b) ? b : a;
   }
 };
```

`

Comment: Functions in c++ are not first class, So they are not directly passed.
However there are ways to pass functions as argument.
1. Function pointer
2. using function<> from c++>11 functional module.
Refer to this.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/passing-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-cpp/